# datatables return [object HTMLInputElement]

Tags: javascript, datatables

I use ColumnDef to create column in datatables and it return [object HTMLInputElement]  in the note texterea but the other was fine

```
columnDefs: [
            {
                title: "STT",
                targets: 0,
                data: null,
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    return (meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1);
                },
            },
            {
                title: "Loại sản phẩm*",
                targets: 1,
                data: null,
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    return '<textarea style="width: 300px;" id="productname' + data.id + '" type="text" onchange="ChangeProductName(\'' + data.id + '\',this)" name="' + data.id + '" value="' + data.productname + '">' + data.productname + '</textarea>';
                }
            },
            {
                title: "Điều kiện*",
                targets: 2,
                data: null,
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    return '<textarea style="width: 300px;" id="condition' + data.id + '" type="text" onchange="ChangeCondition(\'' + data.id + '\',this)" name="' + data.id + '" value="' + data.condition + '">' + data.condition + '</textarea>';
                }
            },
            {
                title: "Rebate(%)*",
                targets: 3,
                data: null,
                width: "70",
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    return '<div><input id="rebate' + data.id + '" type="number" style="width: 70px;" onchange="ChangeRebate(\'' + data.id + '\',this)" name="' + data.id + '" value="' + data.rebate + '"></div>';

                }
            },
            {
                title: "Ghi chú",
                targets: 4,
                data: null,
                /*width: "250",*/
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    return '<textarea id="note' + data.id + '" type="text" onchange="ChangeNote(\'' + data.id + '\',this)" name="' + data.id + '" value="' + data.note + '">' + data.note + '</textarea>';

                }
            },
            {
                title: "",
                targets: 5,
                data: null,
                className: "dt-center",
                width: "70",
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    // return '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i style="cursor: pointer;font-size: 25px;padding-bottom: 30px;" class="fa fa-trash removePG" aria-hidden="true" onclick=removePG(\'' + data.id + '\')></i>';
                    return '<div class="btn btn-danger removePG" style="cursor: pointer;font-size:25px;" ><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></div>';
                }
            },
        ]
```

Here is the display
[image]

Why only the textarea in note have this error

I appreciate every explanation and suggestion about how I should fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clearly textarea value issue. Looks like data.note is object, but it've got to be a string. Check it twice)